# Display string of Json deserialized variable in label in usercontrol

Tags: c#, json, label

I have a deserialized Json inside a variable called "Uinfo" in a class "Userinfo" like this:

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dii2Y.png)

And my class Information I have this:

```
public class Information
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I want to do is display the string of "username" that is in the variable "Uinfo" in a label in the usercontrol "dashboardcontrol"

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp7m3.png)

How can I display the string contained in "Uinfo" in the label11 in dashboarcontrol?

[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Sdw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the label's text equal to the string property

```
label11.Text = Uinfo[0].username;
```

Comment: His Uinfo is an array... label11.Text = Uinfo[0].username;

Comment: Ah you're right, thank you for the correction.

Comment: I cant just simply do that because if you see PIC2 you would see that dashboardcontrol and the class are separate so Im guessing I would have to invoke the variable inside the class and thats where im struggling

Comment: @Dragonsan'sGameplays it sounds like your question is... 'How can I reference one object from within another object... or in your case... 'How can I reference an object, `UInfo`, from within a custom control'. Your post doesn't contain enough information to answer this, but some ideas are, pass the object via the control's constructor, or create a property on the control and set the property when you instantiate the control.

Comment: Perfect. Could you please elaborate in code an example of how to do that? Sorry if my question is unclear but im still learning as you can see

Comment: You could try making Uinfo a public static variable? Can't help much without more insight into how your app is structured.